# Monitoring files in linux

Tags: linux, shell

How to build a tool in Ubuntu 16.04 that can monitor a given folder/directory in every 5 minutes (or specified time) and can check if it contains any file or not (file can be of any format)? What things I need to learn for doing this task? Can I do this with the help of python script or am I required to learn shell scripting.

Answer (score 1):

Try with incron. Incron is for monitoring filesystem activity. It consists of a daemon and a table manipulator. You can use it a similar way as the regular cron. The difference is that the inotify cron handles filesystem events rather than time periods

Comment: is it possible to check whether the folder contains any file through inchron, in every 5 minutes. can you share a link for studying inchrone

Comment: https://www.howtoforge.com/tutorial/how-to-run-commands-on-file-or-directory-changes-with-incron-on-ubuntu-16-04/

Answer (score 1):

With python i would try to use [watchdog](https://github.com/gorakhargosh/watchdog). Used it several times to listen for events in large directory trees and its awesome and easy:

```
import time
from watchdog.observers import Observer
from watchdog.events import LoggingEventHandler

if __name__ == "__main__":

    path = '.'
    event_handler = LoggingEventHandler()
    observer = Observer()
    observer.schedule(event_handler, path, recursive=True)
    observer.start()

    try:
        while True:
            time.sleep(1)
    except KeyboardInterrupt:
        observer.stop()

    observer.join()
```

With this snippet, you will get everything that happens within the defined `path` as event. To do more with them, dive into the [documentation](https://pythonhosted.org/watchdog/) of watchdog.

Comment: @ fechnert Thanks for adding the knowledge about watchdog to me, but I want to monitor in every 10 min, about whether the folder contains any file or not.. Is it possible with watchdog? or can you provide me with other methods through python. Thanks

Comment: In this case try [`os.walk()`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/os.html#os.walk)